# Allowing inline assembly on cmake build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to build an exe using `cmake` and no IDE for this project https://github.com/cyberquarks/fubi

This is the cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Fubi)

set(SOURCES DbgHelpDll.cpp Fubi.cpp SysExports.cpp fubimain.cpp stdafx.cpp)
add_executable(Fubi ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(Fubi PRIVATE DbgHelp)

set_property(TARGET Fubi PROPERTY ENTRY_POINT "fubimain.cpp")

include_directories("C:/local/boost_1_73_0")
link_directories(C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.2)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 6.0)
```

While I build it with:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ..
$ cmake --build .
```

During the build process it throws this error:

```
Fubi.cpp
C:\fubi\Fubi.cpp(40,5): error C4235: nonstandard extension used: '__asm' keyword not supported on this architecture [C:\fubi\build\Fubi.vcxproj]
```

Which is this code:

```
DWORD Fubi::Call_cdecl( const void* args, size_t sz, DWORD func )
{
    DWORD rc;               
    __asm
    {
    // ...
    }
    return ( rc );
}
```

How can I use cmake to build the executable and allow the inline assembly code to compile also?

Update:

The same project works when using CLion IDE to build and run it.

Toolchains:

[image]

Debug config:

[image]

Cmake settings:

[image]

Run config:

[image]

Comment: _",,,inline assembly is not supported on the ARM and x64 processors. ,,,"_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=msvc-170  So you either need to build for 32-bit or go the whole external assembly file and masm route.

Comment: @RichardCritten hi, the same code/project works if I use CLion, using the build and run command from the IDE, also using Visual Studio 2019 IDE I can run the program on the same machine.

Comment: Is CLion defaulting to 32-bit  or using a different compiler ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I added screenshots of all the config I have for CLion